# Laravel project installed with laragon is forcing https in google chrome

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome, laragon

I have a laravel project which is installed with laragon and I was working for few days nicely. Now after a sudden stop of my pc (because of electricity unavailability) I can no longer access the local site in chrome and it is forcing me to an https location. I then opened the site in mozila and it's working there perfectly.

Here what chrome shows as error

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
school.dev sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

What could be the reason and the solution for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Laravel and everything to do with Chrome. They recently put a release that forces .dev, .app, and a few other TLDs to use HTTPS. The best fix is to use .local instead of another TLD.

src: [Chromium transport_security_state_static.json changelog](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/master/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json)

Comment: to buttress @aynber, the extension can be anything you like expect for the above mentioned. I simple changed my to **{name}.mc** after myself. freaking loving

Comment: Just make sure whatever extension you choose isn't one that's already registered, just to make sure the problem doesn't crop up later. `.local` is already designated for local networks, so it should never have that problem.

Answer (score -1):

I face similar issue yesterday, it took me lots of time to actually  understand this issue but  not to waste much of time, i decided to switch to other browser like Mozilla Firefox and use http instead of https to continue my work.

Comment: Simply right click on Laragon to go to preference setting, then change the .dev in {name}.**dev** to anything you like such as {name}.mc. With that you get solution rather than avoiding the problem

Comment: This isn't a solution. It's a hacky workaround at best.