# 500 error on local Laragon website

Tags: laravel, virtualhost, laragon

I usually don't have any problem with Laragon as it works pretty good. I had no problem using Laravel.
But recently, my laptop made a Windows update, and since it restarted, nothing works anymore.
By nothing, I mean that when I try to load my virtual host "foo.dev", I have a 500 error without any info. So I tried the old way by going on localhost/www/foo/public and it loaded my website. Great !
But new bad news, impossible to connect to the database, even using a software, as if the password had been changed...

I don't have any idea on how to fix these problems and where does the problem comes from...So I'm asking for your help, if anyone has already faced a similar problem and reached to solve it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I guess when updated your windows, Chrom also updated and apparently Chrome made new release that forces .dev, .app, and a few other TLDs to use HTTPS. The best fix is to use .local instead of another TLD.
[see this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47794808/laravel-project-installed-with-laragon-is-forcing-https-in-google-chrome)